# Unable to click on href link using selenium

Tags: selenium, href

I am unable to open a href link using the code below. I have used the code to store the tag names as web elements and iterated to point to my target href. Please kindly suggest what to change in the above code as the output indicates that there are null references.

```
String path="http://google.com";

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(path);
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("hdmi");
driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();


//first get all the <a> elements
List<WebElement> linkList=driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

//now traverse over the list and check
for(int i=0 ; i<linkList.size() ; i++)
{
    if(linkList.get(i).getAttribute("href").contains("http://www.hdmi.org/"))
    {
        linkList.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you downloaded and 'chromeDriver' binary?

Comment: what you mean "unable to open"? Do you get any errors?

Comment: @Andersson  the functionality of the code is to open the href link , the code opens google.com and the sends "hdmi" as the keyword. once it opens multiple references to "hdmi" , it will not progress further , where the href link is present.

Comment: guys i am new to testing , can i know what is 'chromeDriver' binary;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to loop through the links in this case. You can just locate the one you want and click on it. You will have to have a brief wait as the results load or it won't work. I'm guessing that's why your code wasn't working.

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("hdmi");
driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a[href*='http://www.hdmi.org/']"))).click();
```

NOTE: There is more than one link that matches your requirements but this code clicks only the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement some `wait` before finding the list as below :-

```
String path="http://google.com";

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(path);
driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("hdmi");
driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

//wait..
Thread.sleep(2000);

//first get all the <a> elements
List<WebElement> linkList = driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"));

//now traverse over the list and check
for(WebElement el : linkList)
{
    String link = el.getAttribute("href");
    if((link !=null) && (link.contains("http://www.hdmi.org/")))
    {
        el.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

For more better solution you can use `WebDriverWait` here to find that link only without using loop as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("hdmi");
driver.findElement(By.name("btnG")).click();

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
WebElement link = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'http://www.hdmi.org/')]")));
link.click();
```

Hope it will help you...:)

Comment: Using `Thread.sleep()` in cases like this is not a good practice and isn't necessary.